# Interpolate surface of 3D cylinder in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

I have a dataset that describes a point cloud of a 3D cylinder (`xx,yy,zz,C`):
[image: 3D point cloud]

and I would like to make a surface plot from this dataset, similar to this
[image]

In order to do this I thought I could interpolate my scattered data using `TriScatteredInterp` onto a regular grid and then plot it using `surf`:

```
F = TriScatteredInterp(xx,yy,zz);
max_x = max(xx); min_x = min(xx);
max_y = max(yy); min_y = min(yy);
max_z = max(zz); min_z = min(zz);
xi = min_x:abs(stepSize):max_x;
yi = min_y:abs(stepSize):max_y;
zi = min_z:abs(stepSize):max_z;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(xi,yi);
qz = F(qx,qy);
F = TriScatteredInterp(xx,yy,C);
qc = F(qx,qy);

figure
surf(qx,qy,qz,qc);
axis image
```

This works really well for convex and concave objects but ends in this for the cylinder:
[image]

Can anybody help me as to how to achieve a nicer plot?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Delaunay triangulation?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html

```
load seamount
tri = delaunay(x,y);
trisurf(tri,x,y,z);
```

[image: plot]

There is also TriScatteredInterp

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triscatteredinterp.html

```
ti = -2:.25:2;
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(ti,ti);
qz = F(qx,qy);
mesh(qx,qy,qz);
hold on;
plot3(x,y,z,'o');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are loking for is the [Convex hull](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) function. See its documentation.

> K = convhull(X,Y,Z) returns the 3-D convex hull of the points (X,Y,Z),
> where X, Y, and Z are column vectors. K is a triangulation
> representing the boundary of the convex hull. K is of size mtri-by-3,
> where mtri is the number of triangular facets. That is, each row of K
> is a triangle defined in terms of the point indices.

Example in 2D

```
xx = -1:.05:1; yy = abs(sqrt(xx));
[x,y] = pol2cart(xx,yy);
k = convhull(x,y);
plot(x(k),y(k),'r-',x,y,'b+')
```

[image]

Use plot to plot the output of convhull in 2-D. Use trisurf or trimesh to plot the output of convhull in 3-D.

Answer (score 0):

A cylinder is the collection of all points equidistant to a line. So you know that your `xx`, `yy` and `zz` data have one thing in common, and that is that they all should lie at an equal distance to the line of symmetry. You can use that to generate a new cylinder (line of symmetry taken to be z-axis in this example):

```
% best-fitting radius 
% NOTE: only works if z-axis is cylinder's line of symmetry
R = mean( sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2) );

% generate some cylinder
[x y z] = cylinder(ones(numel(xx),1));

% adjust z-range and set best-fitting radius
z = z * (max(zz(:))-min(zz(:))) + min(zz(:));
x=x*R;
y=y*R;

% plot cylinder
surf(x,y,z)
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not quite what I am after. Rather than fitting a new cylinder I would like to plot a surface based on the measured point cloud. I tried with triangulation before but this doesn't produce quite the right results for me either as lots of my datapoints then no longer feature on the map.

Answer (score 0):

TriScatteredInterp is good for fitting 2D surfaces of the form z = f(x,y), where f is a single-valued function. It won't work to fit a point cloud like you have.

Since you're dealing with a cylinder, which is, in essence, a 2D surface, you can still use TriScatterdInterp if you convert to polar coordinates, and, say, fit radius as a function of angle and height--something like:

```
% convert to polar coordinates:
theta = atan2(yy,xx);
h = zz;
r = sqrt(xx.^2+yy.^2);

% fit radius as a function of theta and h
RFit = TriScatteredInterp(theta(:),h(:),r(:));

% define interpolation points
stepSize = 0.1;
ti = min(theta):abs(stepSize):max(theta);
hi = min(h):abs(stepSize):max(h);
[qx,qy] = meshgrid(ti,hi);
% find r values at points:
rfit = reshape(RFit(qx(:),qy(:)),size(qx));
% plot
surf(rfit.*cos(qx),rfit.*sin(qx),qy)
```